# navbar in ruby on rails with yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

So after a couple of days of trawling various forums, tutorials etc - I'm still no closer to doing what is seemingly something straightforward - namely, have links on a Navbar populate a named yield with the contents of a partial. I'm probably missing something fundamental, but hey! I've asked this before, but I don't think I worded the question too well, so hopefully this time I'll do better!

My view:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.ico">

      <title>Software Dev Tools Web UI</title>

    </head>
        <div class="container">
          <!-- Static navbar -->
          <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MARS Web UI</a>
              </div>
              <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
XXXXXXXXX
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li class="active"><a href="./">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
          </div>
        </div>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
        <%= yield :mainbody %>
        </div>
    </body>



    <script>
        $(".nav li").on("click", function() {
            $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });

    </script>

    </html>
```

Where I have inserted XXXXXXX above, I have tried:

```
<li><a href="<%= content_for :mainbody do; render 'authentication/perforce'; end %>">P4</a></li>
<li><a href="<%= content_for :mainbody do; render 'authentication/p4_output'; end %>">P4 Output</a></li>
```

This simply rendered both "perforce" and "p4_output" partials one below the other, and clicking the navbar options had no effect.

So then I figured maybe something more like this was required:

```
<li class="active"><%= link_to "Perforce", {:action => 'renderp4'}, :remote => true %></li>
<li class="active"><%= link_to "Perforce", {:action => 'renderp4_output'}, :remote => true %></li>
```

But at this point I came to a grinding halt, not knowing how what would be needed in my "renderp4" and "renderp4_output" actions so as to return HTML to my mainbody yield - if it is even possible?!?

Hopefully what I am trying to achieve is obvious - while I appreciate and acknowledge I am probably rather wide of the mark with my solution currently, any guidance would be appreciated. As I say, I've hunted around, but just hit a brick wall!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a renderp4.js.erb file

```
$('.container').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript render "authentication/perforce" %>');
```

Comment: Thanks Baloo - please forgive my ignorance here, learning as fast as I can here.. where in the project hierarchy should that go? 

I assume I also need the same for p4_output etc... or can they all go in a single file - with some sort of function definitions?

How do I add the appropriate call in my view?

Thanks for your patience! :)

Comment: You'd need a seperate file for p4_output.  Put them in the directory the controller the action is on uses.  Should work with your link to actions.  Basically your index action uses index.html.erb so if you're calling the action renderp4 the file should be named renderp4.js.erb

Comment: So sorry Baloo, but to make it suitably idiot proof for me... the code above is /app/views/mainpage/post_login.html.erb - corresponding to my /app/controllers/mainpage controller. The view code I wish to include (perforce, and p4_output) is currently part of my authentication controller - ie under /app/views/authentication folder... But are you saying I need to create /app/views/mainpage/renderp4.js.erb??  Also, does the `$('.container')` need to be amended to reflect the precise container in my post_login view I wish to render in? THANK YOU AGAIN :)

Comment: Yes, it'd be better to set an id on the container and use $('#whatever-you-called-it').

If the renderp4 action is on the mainpage controller it'll need to be in /mainpage/renderp4.js.erb also any variables/db queriers /authentication/perforce needs will need to be done in the renderp4 action too

Comment: Ok - understanding is DEFINITELY growing! So I now have renderp4.js.erb alongside post_login.html.erb under /views/mainpage... But now when I click Perforce on the navbar, I get an `ActionController::URLGenerationError - No route matches{:action=>"renderp4", controller=>"mainpage"}` error?

Comment: Is it setup in config/routes.rb?

Comment: Duh! It wasn't... but it is now! Sadly I cannot vote up your response owing to lack of rating! :( but THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!