# AJAX call to controller action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a "mainpage" controller, with a view of the same name, containing a boostrap navbar along the top. Upon clicking the various options of the navbar, a div at the bottom of the view has it's contents replaced with an appropriate partial (using a "replaceWith / render" call in a .js.erb file)

For one such partial, I have a form with 2 select boxes. These need to be populated dynamically on loading of the partial, so I am trying to put some AJAX together. Below is my AJAX efforts thus far (found at the end of my partial's code):

```
<script>
    // Get Perforce Suites
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // modern browser
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else // proper old school! IE 6 and older. Does anyone...? Never mind...
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            //processing of responsetext to go in here
        }

    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/perforce_sync/getPerforce", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    alert (xmlhttp.responseText);
</script>
```

So you can see I still have the response processing to do... but as it stands, the alert(xmlhttp.responseText) is coming back empty.

I'm guessing its the xmlhttp.open that is wrong - I'm trying to call an action (getPerforce) in the "perforce_sync" controller. I'm not getting any errors in the server output - but nor  am I getting anything back from the request!

Note - the above script was based mostly on http://tinyurl.com/ygzdwg with the URL based on what I read here http://tinyurl.com/netps6v

Any guidance welcomed! Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason you're using pure JS for the ajax XHR call? I.E Do you now use JQuery?

Comment: No reason whatsoever! I'm very new to the whole world of Ruby, Rails, jQuery, AJAX etc, so have been googling for my life! So I've now come up with this (not sure how well it'll post in a comment, but... 
`var request = $.get("/perforce_sync/getPerforce");
    request.success(function(result){
        alert("res: " + result)
    })
    request.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert ("err: " + errorThrown);
    })`

And this returns "err: Not found". So it seems I was right that the URL is wrong - but not sure what it needs to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain how to use ajax:

---

[**Ajax**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Ajax stands for **Asynchronous Javascript And XML** - which basically means it uses Javascript to send a request to a server on your behalf

The JS in your browser can then handle the response, allowing you to manipulate the DOM as required (update page without refresh)

Although you can use what you've got, [JQuery has made Ajax a lot easier](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/perforce_sync/getPerforce",
   data: [[form data]]
   success: function(data) { 
       //append data to DOM
   }
});
```

Calling this will allow you to handle the data you need from your controller without refresh

---

**Code**

To give you specific info, you've mentioned that your application needs to populate another select box depending on the value of the first select

I'd do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
scope module: 'perforce_sync' do
   get "getPerforce", to: "controller#action"
end

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$("#select1").on("change", function(){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: "/perforce_sync/getPerforce"
        data: $(this).val(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            //handle data
        },
        error: function(data) {
           alert("error");
        }
    });
}); 

#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def action
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry Rich, I think I may have caused some confusion. The select is not populated based on the selection in another. Perforce is our software version control system. We have an API for it, and I have written a function in perforce_sync_controller.rb that accesses that API, returning a list of files. I want to call that function, as part of rendering my _perforceSync partial, which is rendered when I click the "Perforce" tab on a navbar in my mainpage/mainpage. (I'll try to explain what seems to be the problem better in another comment!)

Comment: No problem - looking forward to the new comment!

Comment: The problem I think is that /perforce_sync/getPerforce (perforce_sync being the controller, getPerforce being an action therein), as a URL is wrong - but If I am understanding correctly, the "scope module" section in your code above should fix that (replacing controller#action with perforce_sync#getPerforce of course!) ... However, rubymine is now grumbling - expecting a : or ; or end of line after the 'get "GetPerforce"' and likewise after the "to:"?  Hopefully I've explained myself a bit better now?

Comment: I had a syntax error in my routes file - needed a `,`. Let me read your comment & see if I can get to the bottom of it

Comment: Cool that fixed routes.rb :) So to try to add to my awful explanation: From localhost://mainpage I click "P4" on a navbar. This prompts a <div> within mainpage to be replaced (via a .js.erb) with the contents of my Partial - which includes the select. This select, needs to be populated with the results of perforce_sync/getPerforce action

Comment: Okay, so you're literally just populating the div from a link click?

Comment: mainpage.html.erb: <li class="active"><%= link_to "Perforce", :action =>  'renderp4', :remote => true %></a></li>           routes.rb: get 'renderp4' => 'mainpage#renderp4'            renderp4.js.erb: $('#MainPage').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript render "perforce_sync/perforceSync" %>')                 and in perforce_sync/_perforceSync.erb    I want the jQuery to call the GetPerforce action in the perforce_sync controller - and use the results to populate the select in perforce_sync/_perforceSync.erb :)

Comment: Hmmmm okay - where does `renderp4` come into it?

Comment: renderp4 is (as I understand it) automatically converted to "renderp4.js.erb" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22633017/navbar-in-ruby-on-rails-with-yield   (gotta run for now Rich - appreciate your efforts, and catch up tomorrow hopefully - thanks again!)

Comment: Morning Rich... So I've gotten a bit further - But in order to fully explain where I am now, it seemed sensible to raise a new question so as to be able to post relevant code, nicely formatted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683387/jquery-call-to-controller-action-is-not-as-expected .... With that in mind, I'll accept your answer to this question - you've undoubtedly gotten me that much closer! Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks Steve - let me check your new question for you!