# jQuery call to controller action is not as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following **jQuery**:

```
var request = $.get("getPerforceSuites");
request.success(function(result){
    alert("res: " + result)
})
request.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert ("err: " + errorThrown);
})
```

And the following entry in **routes.rb**:

```
  get "getPerforceSuites", to: "perforce_sync#getPerforce"
```

and in my **perforce_sync_controller.rb**:

```
  def getPerforce
    # return getRemoteSuites
    puts "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
    puts "Called getPerforce"
    puts "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
    return "Hi!"
  end
```

Initially this wasn't working - until I created an empty getPerforce.erb.html file in /views/perforce_sync... Now I can confidently say The getPerforce action is definitely being called, since the 3 "puts" lines appear in the rails server log. However, I had expected the "alert("res: " + result)" to show "Hi!"... But instead, I'm getting a whole heap of HTML, seemingly a document header (but from what file, I've no idea!):

```
res: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test1</title>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/authentication.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />  ***... SNIP ... ***
```

Can anyone explain what I'm getting wrong here? I'm kinda new to jQuery - but no amount of googling has resulted in my recognising the issue!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the way rails responds to controller actions. By default, if you don't call `render` in the controller action, then it will look in your views folder for a template. That's why it wanted you to create a `getPerforce.erb.html` file.

To make it just return plain text, in the controller you can write:

```
render :text => 'Hi!'
```

If you are doing AJAX stuff, then typically you will want to return JSON, you can also do this in the controller like so

```
render :json => {:data_key => 'A value'}
```

Comment: Nail struck firmly on head! Thanks SlicedPan! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the reason why the `getPerforce.js.erb` is outputting an `<html>` header is because the server is already outputting content with your `puts` commands

---

**HTML**

Although the official terminology escapes me, you must remember Rails is a framework based on HTTP -- meaning any outputted has to be transmitted to the client

As such, if you're outputting text, it's got to be rendered, which I would guess is done with the Rails HTML rendering engine

---

**Controller**

As alluded to by `Slicedpan`, I would get rid of any direct outputs (puts) from the controller.

You should use this:

```
#app/controllers/perforce_sync_controller.rb
def getPerforce
   respond_to do |format|
       format.html { @return = "Called getPerforce" }
       format.js { @return = "hi" }
   end
end

#app/views/perforce_sync/getPerforce.js.erb
alert("<%=j @return %>");
```

Comment: Thanks again Rich... as you and I sort of mentioned on a previous question of mine, the getPerforce action actually goes off to a 3rd party API and returns a list of files. As such, the following is now returning (what is actually just CSV!) nicely: `def getPerforce
    result = @@p4object.getRemoteSuites
    render :json => result
  end`

Comment: Just a final comment from me for now, to say a huge thanks again to both Rich and SlicedPan for their recent patience and support on a few of my questions. You've both brought my Rails skills forward a lot! Thanks! :)

Comment: No problem! Keep asking!! :D